# How old are Eleven and Kali?

Tags: stranger-things

In *Stranger Things* season 2, we're introduced to a new character, Kali.

Since it's a bit relevant to the timeline of the show, I'm wondering if we know the actual ages of Eleven and Kali, or at least their ages relative to one another (such as 4 years apart).

Has there been any clues about this released, whether hidden in the show or in something like an interview with the Duffer Brothers?

Answer (score 11):

### Eleven (011)

We know from context that **Eleven is approximately twelve years old**, based on how long she was missing.

> *"Twelve years? **Twelve years she's been looking for her.** And then she [Eleven]
> shows up at Benny's five nights ago, which means we've got a chance."*
>
> <sub><sup>[Chapter 6 - The Monster](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=stranger-things-2016&episode=s01e06)</sup></sub>

Interestingly, in the [original draft script](http://c-7npsfqifvt34x24mb-tdsffox78sjufsx2edpn.g00.wikia.com/g00/3_c-7tusbohfsuijoht.x78jljb.dpn_/c-7NPSFQIFVT34x24iuuqx3ax2fx2fmb-tdsffox78sjufs.dpnx2fx78q-dpoufoux2fvqmpbetx2f3127x2f19x2fTusbohfs_Uijoht_2y12_-_Qjmpu.qeg_$/$/$/$/$/$) she was explicitly stated to be ten years of age.

> A YOUNG GIRL, **10,** emerges out of the woods.

---

### Kali (008)

Kali's age isn't stated, but we see her in a [UK primary school](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_education#United_Kingdom) uniform in one of the newspaper articles about her disappearance. That means that she was at least five and no more than eleven years of age when she was taken, presumably to act as a [*control subject*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_control).

Since we know how long the experiments lasted (e.g. 12 years) **we can place Kali's age at about 17 to 23 years of age.** Obviously this could be subject to change if we find out that she was abducted prior to Eleven's abduction.

Comment: Kali said she _escaped_, so I'm presuming she was not in the program for the full 12 years?

Comment: @CreationEdge - There's also quite a few unanswered questions about how long she was in the program before Eleven got there. If we get more info, I'll update with a more accurate number.

Comment: The _Beyond Stranger Things_ show occasionally reveals tidbits like that. At least, episode 1 had good BTS info

Answer (score 0):

Kalis age WAS stated in the first Stranger Things episode she was in. She showed her drivers license and it proved that she was 19 years when she reunited with Eleven.

Comment: Can you provide a screen-shot to back this up?

Comment: Or at least an indication of *when* in the episode this happened, so that other people can find it for themselves?

Comment: She was in the opening scene of  S 2 Ep 1, committing a crime. And we know she has illusion powers. So without further details, such as a timestamp and episode number, not sure this offers any proof.